# Creating my own ListControl, some problems in Delphi

Tags: delphi, listbox, controls, custom-controls

Some time ago I have decided to create my own `ListControl`. What is mean under `ListControl` - is a control that similar to standard `TListBox` in Delphi.
I know, it is 'reinventing a wheel', but I want to finish my control.
So, I implemented not so much features in that control like `TListBox` has, but my control allows:

1. Add items;
2. Select item;
3. Navigate through items via keyboard (arrow keys Up an Down).

I plan to implement my ScrollBar, but this is another topic.

But I have a problem: when summary height of items is more than control's height and last item selected and I try to increase control's height I got a 'blank space', but I want to 'scroll' items down to fill blank space.

[image]

At the picture above you can see that control has lack of items to draw them onto 'blank space'.

May be I explain my problem not so clear, but do next:

1. Put standard `TListBox` on form and set its height equal `100` px;
2. Put standard `TrackBar` on form, set Max value to `100` and in event `OnChange` write this:

   ```
   ListBox1.Height := ListBox1.Height + TrackBar1.Position;
   ```
3. Add 12 items at this `Listbox`;
4. Compile project and select last item in `Listbox`, then begin to change its height via `TrackBar`. You will see, that 'invisible top items' are come from top to down one by one.

That effect I want to add in my control, but I have no idea why.

Control's code

```
unit aListBox;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  StdCtrls,
  ExtCtrls,
  StrUtils,
  Dialogs,
  Math;

type
  { main class }
  TaListBox       = class;


  {>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>}
  TaListBox = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    FItemBmp: TBitmap;

    FEnabled: Boolean;
    FSelected: Boolean;

    FItems: TStringList;
    FItemHeight: Integer;
    FCurrentItemIndex: Integer;
    FMode: Integer;
    FGlobalY: Integer;
    FScrollOffset: Integer;
    FDownScroll: Integer;

    procedure SetItems(value: TStringList);

    procedure WMSIZE(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
    procedure WMGETDLGCODE(var Message: TWMGETDLGCODE); message WM_GETDLGCODE;

    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;

    function GetItemIndex: Integer;
    function GetVisibleItemsCount: Integer;
    function GetScrollItemIndex: Integer;

    procedure PaintItemStandard(BmpInOut: TBitmap; AMode, AIndex: Integer);
    procedure PaintControlStandard(ACanvas: TCanvas; AMode: Integer);

    procedure Paint; override;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Click; override;

    property ItemIndex    : Integer read FCurrentItemIndex;

  published
    { Published declarations }
    property Items     : TStringList read FItems write FItems;

    property OnClick;
  end;
  {<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<}


implementation


{ TaListBox }


procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyControl', [TaListBox]);
end;

constructor TaListBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  Inherited Create(AOwner);

  { standard declarations }
  ControlStyle := ControlStyle + [csOpaque, csCaptureMouse, csDoubleClicks];
  Width := 100;
  Height := 120;

  DoubleBuffered := true;

  { control's declarations }
  FItemBmp := TBitmap.Create;

  FEnabled := true;
  FSelected := false;

  FItems := TStringList.Create;

  FItemHeight := 20;
  FCurrentItemIndex := -1;
  FScrollOffset := 0;
  FDownScroll := 0;

  FMode := 1;
end;

destructor TaListBox.Destroy;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FItemBmp);
  FreeAndNil(FItems);

  Inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TaListBox.Click;
begin
  if FEnabled then
    Inherited Click
  else
    Exit;
end;

procedure TaListBox.SetItems(value: TStringList);
begin
  Invalidate;
end;

procedure TaListBox.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
var
  LScrollIndex, LVisibleCount: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  LScrollIndex := FScrollOffset div FItemHeight;
  LVisibleCount := GetVisibleItemsCount;
  if (FItems.Count - LScrollIndex) < LVisibleCount then
    FScrollOffset := FItemHeight * max(0, FItems.Count - GetVisibleItemsCount);
end;

procedure TaListBox.WMGETDLGCODE(var Message: TWMGETDLGCODE);
begin
  Inherited;
  Message.Result := DLGC_WANTARROWS;
end;

procedure TaListBox.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Button = mbLeft then
    begin
      Windows.SetFocus(Handle);

      if PtInRect(Rect(1, 1, Width - 1, Height - 1), Point(X, Y)) then
        FGlobalY := Y - 2;

      if GetItemIndex > FItems.Count - 1 then
        Exit
      else
        begin
          FSelected := true;
          FCurrentItemIndex := GetItemIndex;

          // prevent selecting next item if height too low
          if Height >= FItemHeight then
            if PtInRect(Rect(1, Height - FDownScroll - 1, Width - 1, Height - 1), Point(X, Y)) then
              FScrollOffset := FScrollOffset + FItemHeight;

          Invalidate;
        end;
    end;

  Inherited MouseDown(Button, Shift, X, Y);
end;

procedure TaListBox.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  ScrollIndex: Integer;
begin
  Inherited KeyDown(Key, Shift);

  if FEnabled then
    begin
      case Key of
        VK_UP:
          begin
            if FCurrentItemIndex = 0 then
              Exit
            else
              begin
                if (FCurrentItemIndex + 1) > 0 then
                  begin
                    Dec(FCurrentItemIndex);
                    ScrollIndex := FScrollOffset div FItemHeight;
                    if FCurrentItemIndex < ScrollIndex then
                      FScrollOffset := FScrollOffset - FItemHeight;
                  end;
              end;
          end;
        VK_DOWN:
          begin
            if FCurrentItemIndex = FItems.Count - 1 then
              Exit
            else
              begin
                if (FCurrentItemIndex + 1) < FItems.Count then
                  begin
                    Inc(FCurrentItemIndex);
                    ScrollIndex := FScrollOffset div FItemHeight;
                    if (FCurrentItemIndex - GetVisibleItemsCount + 1) > ScrollIndex then
                      FScrollOffset := FScrollOffset + FItemHeight;
                  end;
              end;
          end;
      end;

      Invalidate;
    end
  else
    Exit;
end;

function TaListBox.GetItemIndex: Integer;
begin
  Result := (FGlobalY + FScrollOffset) div FItemHeight;
end;

function TaListBox.GetVisibleItemsCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := Height div FItemHeight;
end;

function TaListBox.GetScrollItemIndex: Integer;
begin
  Result := FScrollOffset div FItemHeight;
end;

procedure TaListBox.PaintItemStandard(BmpInOut: TBitmap; AMode, AIndex: Integer);
var
  Text: String;
  R: TRect;
begin
  BmpInOut.Width := Width - 2;
  BmpInOut.Height := FItemHeight;

  case AMode of
    1:
      begin
        if FSelected then
        begin
          BmpInOut.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebCrimson;
          BmpInOut.Canvas.Font.Color := clWhite;
        end
        else
        begin
          BmpInOut.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
          BmpInOut.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
        end;
        BmpInOut.Canvas.Pen.Color := clGray;
      end;
    4:
      begin
        BmpInOut.Canvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;
        BmpInOut.Canvas.Pen.Color := clGray;
        BmpInOut.Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
      end;
  end;
  BmpInOut.Canvas.FillRect(BmpInOut.Canvas.ClipRect);

  // paint item's text
  if AIndex = - 1 then
    Exit
  else
    BmpInOut.Canvas.TextOut(18, 2, FItems.Strings[AIndex]);
end;

procedure TaListBox.PaintControlStandard(ACanvas: TCanvas; AMode: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
  OldSelected: Boolean;
  TempBmp: TBitmap;
begin
  case AMode of
    1:
      begin
        ACanvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
        ACanvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
      end;
    4:
      begin
        ACanvas.Brush.Color := clSilver;
        ACanvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;
      end;
  end;
  ACanvas.Rectangle(Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));

  // calculate DownButton size
  FDownScroll := Height - GetVisibleItemsCount * FItemHeight - 1 {top border pixel} - 1 {bottom border pixel};

  // create output bitmap
  TempBmp := TBitmap.Create;
  TempBmp.Width := Width - 2;
  TempBmp.Height := Height - 2;

  // turn off selected flag
  OldSelected := FSelected;
  FSelected := false;

  for i:=0 to FItems.Count - 1 do
    begin
      PaintItemStandard(FItemBmp, FMode, i);
      TempBmp.Canvas.Draw(0, 0 + (FItemHeight * i) - FScrollOffset, FItemBmp);
    end;

  // output result
  ACanvas.Draw(1, 1, TempBmp);

  // restore selected flag
  FSelected := OldSelected;
  if FSelected then
    begin
      // paint selected item
      PaintItemStandard(FItemBmp, FMode, FCurrentItemIndex);
      ACanvas.Draw(1, 1 + (FItemHeight * FCurrentItemIndex) - FScrollOffset, FItemBmp);
    end;

  // free resources
  FreeAndNil(TempBmp);
end;

procedure TaListBox.Paint;
begin
  if FEnabled then
    PaintControlStandard(Canvas, 1)
  else
    PaintControlStandard(Canvas, 4);
end;


end.
```

I hope I can find some help here.
Thank you for your attention!

P.S.
In the source code was added implementation of scrolling items by changing control's size, written by **Tom Brunberg**.

P.S.S.
Thanks to user **fantaghirocco** for formatting my question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your directions to create a standard `TListBox` I noted, as you said, that the number of visible items increased when increasing the list box (regardless of any item being selected).

**But**, decreasing the size did not scroll items up again, regardless of any item being selected. I understand that you ask about the same functionality, since you refer to the standard `TListBox`.

Add to the `uses` clause and to the `TaListBox` class declaration:

```
uses ... Math;
  ...

  TaListBox = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    procedure WMSize(var Message: TWMSize); message WM_SIZE;
```

and to the implementation

```
procedure TaListBox.WMSize(var Message: TWMSize);
var
  LScrollIndex, LVisibleCount: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  LScrollIndex := FScrollOffset div FItemHeight;
  LVisibleCount := GetVisibleItemsCount;
  if (FItems.Count - LScrollIndex) < LVisibleCount then
    FScrollOffset := FItemHeight * max(0, FItems.Count - GetVisibleItemsCount);
end;
```

A side note: you use the following kind of expressions in many places, e.g.

```
  Round(FScrollOffset div FItemHeight);
```

The `div` operator means `integer division`. It always returns an integer, thus the call to `Round` is meaningless. Read about `div` and also `mod` in the documentation.

Comment: Tom Brunberg, thank you very much! Your realisation works perfectly! I necessarily will check documentation out for 'div' and 'mod'.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple:

1. Always know how many items can be displayed when your control is a certain height. That means if your clientheight is 100px and an item's height is 10px then you obviously will be able to display 10 items completely whitout anyone being clipped. Save that amount in a variable. Keep as a float because sometimes an item will be clipped. (Visible Count)
2. Keep a variable of which direction you scrolled last. This is important as that will help you decide whether to bring items into view from the bottom or from the top or whether to hide items at the top or bottom when the control's height decreases/increases.
3. Keep an index of the item that is at the top or bottom the last time you scrolled. Whether to keep the top one or the bottom one will depend on which direction you last scrolled (point 2). It will obviously change as you add items, etc.

So let's say the situation is that you have more items than can be displayed and the last time you scrolled was up, so you will keep the item index of the top most visible item. If that index is 0 (zero) then obviously you just need to bring items into view from the bottom. But if that index is for example; 5, then you will keep bringing items into view also from the bottom but only until the Visible Count grows as large or larger than the Item Count in which case you wil start to bring as many items into view from the top as is needed to fill the client area.

You just have to adapt according to last scroll direction and whether the height increases or decreases

Comment: Blurry Sterk, you wrote helpful ideas, I will keep them in mind in further development. Thank you ;)